# Run after Init, before Page_Load

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

After a PostBack caused by `ddlPlant_SelectedIndexChanged`, I need to set set `HttpContext.Current.Session("PlantNumber")`.  This needs to happen after ddlPlant loads in Site.Master, but before the code in Default.aspx needs the value.

```
Public Class SiteMaster Inherits MasterPage
    Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
        If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
            ddlPlant.DataSource = myDataSource
            ddlPlant.DataBind()
            ddlPlant.SelectedValue = "1"
        End If

        HttpContext.Current.Session("PlantNumber") = ddlPlant.SelectedValue  
    End Sub

    Protected Sub ddlPlant_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlPlant.SelectedIndexChanged
    End Sub
End Class


Public Class _Default Inherits Page
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim units As New List(Of EquipmentModel)
        For Each unit As EquipmentModel In getUnits.Out.Results
            If (CStr(unit.Plant_ID) = HttpContext.Current.Session("PlantNumber")) Then
                units.Add(unit)
            End If
        Next

        gvEquipmentUnit.DataSource = units.OrderBy(Function(n) n.Equipment_ID)
        gvEquipmentUnit.DataBind()
End Sub
```

With the code above, when `Session("PlantNumber")` is set after PostBack, ddlPlant.SelectedIndex = Nothing, and ddlPlant.SelectedValue is an empty string.

I've tried moving the `Session("PlantNumber") = ddlPlant.SelectedValue` line to Site.Master's Page_Load instead, but that runs *after* it is needed in Default.aspx.vb

Answer (score 0):

I looked up PreLoad, but apparently it doesn't work for the Master page.

Ultimately, I decided not to use a Session variable, and instead call the control directly from any page that needs that value on load (almost all of them):

```
DirectCast(Master.FindControl("ddlPlant"), DropDownList).SelectedValue
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad suggestion.